# Get rid of import in Groovy Unit Test in IntelliJ

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, junit, dsl, groovydsl

Is it possible to get rid of from import statements in JUnit tests written in Groovy? I know you could do it in groovy scripts  in GroovyShell by changing compiler configuration or import customizer.

I like to do same thing but:

- IntelliJ should still provide code highlight and auto complete (I think I could do this 
  with gdsl file feature of IntelliJ)
- I could still use IntelliJ's JUnit window to see which tests failed and which are passed.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: We have prepared a DSL like API for testing our domain applications. Having to import classes before using them is ugly, we have very small number of static methods. I also want to do this in Groovy Console of IntelliJ but I couldn't figure out how to add my default imports to there too.

Comment: In a modern IDE (like IntelliJ), you won't even notice the imports.  They're managed automatically, and automatically collapsed in the editor.

Comment: I know it, but the people using this DSL's will not be programmers. You can do it in groovy scripts. Groovy has build in support for this feature. I just wan't to customize IntelliJ's JUnit executor to inject my default imports. It seams that only way to do it is modifying source code of IntellIJ plugin. Thanks.